# How can I integrate PayUMoney API for C2C application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment-gateway

I need to integrate [PayUMoney](http://payumoney.com/) for my freelancer job portal, which is developed in PHP Codeigniter.

There are 3 types of user :

1) Employer (Job provider)

2) Freelancer (Person who's doing the job)

3) Broker (the portal takes commission for the transaction)

Currently the employer transfers fund to broker then broker transfers to freelancer. I need to transfer amounts from employer to freelancer directly by transferring the commission to the broker ? With this transaction the broker can get the commission and he doesn't need to track the balances and transfer to freelancer .

Comment: I think you should sign up on PayUMoney as a merchant, then you will find api key and process to use.

Comment: what is the code that i need to use ?....

Comment: Probably you need to follow as @AniketSingh said. I had called their support once and they said they support such actions only in Merchant account and not in individual account.

And in case you have merchant account, please refer their official API doc for more on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set up Payu Gateway with your codeigniter application you need to follow the following steps :

- Go to http://test.payumoney.com
- Signup as a merchant and use any of your valid email address.
- Complete the Business Details and Bank Account Details, you can use any random values as they are not going to verify it.
- Go to Seller Dashboard -> Setting -> My account -> Profile Settings and note down the merchant Id
- Now go to Seller Dashboard -> Setting -> My account -> Merchant Key Salt and email the Merchant Id to the email Id provided at that screen asking for Merchant Key Salt.
- You can also download the payu money integration kit for php and modify the code provided in that kit according to your website
- You can simply replace your test keys with the real ones provided to your customer on behalf of their bank account details after verification.

Some issues that might occur while submitting form will be regarding the product info field, make sure that the value field in the product info sums up to the total amount of transaction.
P.S. The product info is in the form of JSON.

NOTE : For breaking the amount you can modify the productInfo(required) parameter into which is in the form of JSON data providing the name and value key-value pairs. Also make sure that the sum of the value keys is equal to the total amount of transaction.